# My HTML page correctly references an image but it won't display?

Tags: html, image, ftp

I uploaded a "test.html" page to my website, in the root folder, as well as a "filmandmusic.jpg" image (also in the root folder). The image is displaying as a broken jpg, even when I go to the URL of the image itself.

What am I doing wrong?

http://www.bobbymcglynn.com/test.html

Note: this only happens after uploading the site, I'm using Dreamweaver to design my site and everything looks fine when I'm editing the page locally. I'm uploading with FileZilla.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>This is a test page. The "film and music" image should display itself below.</p>
<img src="filmandmusic.jpg" height="75" width="525"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image seems to be corrupted, try re-uploading.

Comment: Fixed! FileZilla was in ASCII transfer mode for some reason. Changed it back to "Auto" and reuploaded my site, everything looks right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML has nothing wrong in that.
if you go to your [website root folder](http://www.bobbymcglynn.com/)
and then open your image, you will see that this image has this form so the uploaded image may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

It Show that the image contains error. Try Uploading a new image.
The error may have been caused due to bad connection problem or the image may be initially damaged.

Answer (score 0):

You probarly dindn't linked the image. Try to fill in the right src path. Maybe it isn't jpg but png. You never now.